# Apache Spark: nondeterministic StackOverflowError when training with GBTRegressor

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Context:

Training with the GBTRegressor on Spark 1.6.3 + Scala on a feature set of about 2000 and with ~1 million rows.

Using 10 EC2 instances with 32 cores each, and we end up with 30 executors each with 10 cores.

HyperParameters/Parameters- Depth:3, Iterations:100, StepSize: 0.1, CacheNodeIds: true, CheckpointInterval:10

Partition size is 5000

Problem:

About 50% of the time we get a stackoverflow error always around stage 1000, other times the trainer finishes fine. Our GBTRegressor is the first `PipelineStage` in the `Pipeline`.

Sample exceptions (though the error has been occuring at varying depths inside `TreeNode`):

```
[Stage 1014:=======================>                       (2514 + 2486) / 5000]
[Stage 1014:=============================>                 (3088 + 1912) / 5000]
[Stage 1014:==================================>            (3666 + 1334) / 5000]
[Stage 1014:========================================>       (4242 + 758) / 5000]
[Stage 1014:==============================================> (4819 + 181) / 5000]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild$lzycompute(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.containsChild(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:300)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:287)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformChildren(TreeNode.scala:321)
```

Another:

```
[Stage 1044:=========================>                     (2692 + 2308) / 5000]
[Stage 1044:==============================>                (3275 + 1725) / 5000]
[Stage 1044:====================================>          (3851 + 1149) / 5000]
[Stage 1044:==========================================>     (4430 + 570) / 5000]
[Stage 1044:=================================================>(4996 + 4) / 5000]
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BindReferences$$anonfun$bindReference$1.applyOrElse(BoundAttribute.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
```

We submit with (also tried upping the thread stack size with Xss but to no avail)

```
spark-submit --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode"
```

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with the stack overflows you're getting but 100 for maxIter seems a lot and 3 for maxDepth seems very small. Also did you try aggressively pruning your trees with minInstancesPerNode and minInfoGain?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So we ran into stack overflows a couple week ago and realized we weren't using CacheNodeIds and checkpointing. After turning those on, the errors seem to have stopped, and we were going up 500 for maxIter at that point with satisfying results.

We started a new round of training a couple days ago (after almost doubling our feature dimension) with 100 maxIter as actually somewhat of a lower bound. We have not tried with the other 2 parameters you mentioned. Could be worth a shot though it does seem to be orthogonal to the stackoverflow problem.

Comment: Follow-up- it seems like using XX:ThreadStackSize was a solution. Xss option apparently doesn't work on Linux instances.